# Use of Nativescript Popup on IOS

Tags: ios, plugins, nativescript

I recently discovered the `nativescript-popup` plugin (https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-popup) and
have used it with great results in my application under Android.
However, I am quite disappointed to find I get no popup at all
under iOS, although it is supposed to work across both platforms.

As a sanity check, I created a very simple test app, independent
of my larger application, with just the following simple code (which is
similar to the plugin example):

```js
exports.showPopup = function (args) {
    console.log('in showPopup')
    const popup = new Popup({
        backgroundColor:'white',
        height: 80,
        width:200,
        unit:'dp',
        elevation:10, // android only
        borderRadius: 12, // android only
        outsideTouchable: true
    });
    const label = new Label();
    label.textWrap = true;
    label.textAlignment = 'center';
    label.text = 'The popup is working';
    popup.showPopup(args.object, label);
    console.log('popup should be showing');
```

and this works as expected on Android, but nothing appears
on iOS.
On both platforms, there is a deprecation warning that originates
from the plugin code, but I don't think that's the problem.
console output for both is:

```js
    in showPopup
    topmost() is deprecated. Use Frame.topmost() instead
    popup should be showing
```

Anyone else using this?  Any advice?

Comment: The version in NPM is 2+ years old, there are some recent changes in Github repo, you might want to take a fork and build it from there.

Comment: I pulled the source from GitHub and built from there.  Indeed, it needed to be migrated to NS 6+.
After doing that, I was able to get the demo working for the simple popup, but the template examples do not, even after adjusting for the deprecated use of Builder.load(),   It seems to be related to the Webpack bundle handling. I suspect there is either a bug or a documentation lapse in the use of Builder.load that I’m not aware of.    
But the template use is not a problem in my context. This update fixes it for the simple sanity code above, but I now have new problems in my feature app.

Comment: In my feature app, I have pop-up controls that host buttons, etc and on iOS these  stop receiving events after any one of them gets hit once. Afterwards, I need to run the app from start again to get any response at all from these events again.

I’m not much up on the underlying native components used here, but I’m guessing that the UI update that accompanies the first (successful) event action affects the native container so that it is not brokering events properly afterward (just  my hunch). I’m not sure I want to make the deep dive to figure this out at this level though.

Comment: Thanks for all the info I’ll try publishing a new build with a fix soon 